# Software engineering student project-get into finance

Tags: project, finance

I have to propose a topic for a software engineering project. I really would like this project to help me to get a job in financial/banking domain.  I’m interested in three areas: Access Control Mechanisms, Data Security or Investment Banking/Trading. I’m also open to other ideas. I will have about 6 months to complete the project. At the moment I don’t have any financial knowledge. I’m not sure what kind of project I could do in order to get basic domain knowledge and meet the deadline. At the same time the level of complexity has to be appropriate for MSc Software Engineering degree. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you think just seeing your project in banking domain people will give you job in banking domain?I work in Insurance domain for the past 5 years and my college project was an "personal digital diary" :)

Comment: I don't think so but it will be definitely helpful, that is why I wrote "help me to get job" :) .

Answer (score 1):

One of the hot issues in investment banking technology over the past few years has been grid computing. If you are comfortable with Monte Carlo analysis and are prepared to learn the math necessary to implement some sort of exotic derivatives pricing, then perhaps something like the construction of a derivatives pricing/risk management application sitting on top of a Map Reduce framework (particularly an OSS one, such as Hadoop) might be interesting. Especially if it also leveraged the EC2 cloud. You could also build upon an existing OSS quant analytics library such as Quantlib.

This is not an insignificant undertaking however! And may well exceed the scope of what you are expected to deliver for a Masters level project. But maybe there is some subset of functionality that might be interesting to work on.

To learn more about derivatives pricing, the canonical text is Hull's [Options, Futures & Other Derivatives](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0135052831)

Comment: Thanks. I have just found "Secure Stock Exchange System Using Web services", what do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

One common "holy grail" application is something that scans market data to construct a "buy" (or "sell") list of securities that meet a specific financial criteria.

Answer (score 0):

We have developed OpenBankingGateway project:

- https://github.com/adorsys/open-banking-gateway

In this project, we have covered

- Data Security (see landing page)
- Access Control Mechanisms (to some extend, mostly limited to request signing)
  parts of your questions

This is a real project used to access banking API and process users' consent to access their bank account information in a secure way. Hope this will help with having some understanding of how things work.

Also, we have developed real Ledgers Sandbox that does payment processing and solves ACL and data encryption challenges present in real banks:

- https://github.com/adorsys/ledgers